# datepickerrange is not working i copied from website link is below

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs, daterangepicker

This code is working on website but on my localhost don't know searching help here ! please help me out

[image: k k my library screenshot please have a look dont know which one is clashing]

working link `http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/`

```js
    
        $(function() { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); });
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.14.4/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.14.4/daterangepicker.min.css">
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="e1" name="e1">
</body>
```

Comment: make sure your  $(function() { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); }); is initialise after your library.

Comment: i did, not working

Comment: Add the higher version jquery and datarange picker

Comment: @RajaRamachandran Can you please help me out in this ? i want customdaterangepicker to select date and filter the data...

Comment: i am using higher version

Comment: see this  link https://github.com/tamble/jquery-ui-daterangepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the versions of libraries:

- daterangepicker - 0.5.0
- momentjs - 2.3.0+

Check the dependencies in the code:
[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2213/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#e1").daterangepicker({});
    });
```

Comment: Bro its not working in my code... in fiddle its perfect what i want but in my code its not working... please help

Comment: @Mohsin check libraries in your website

Comment: i uploaded screenshot of library and working file... at my question

Comment: @Mohsin Put jquery link at the top of the libraries. jquery should be included first. You have included it at the end.

Comment: in console this showing uncaught `jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js` i am giving like this `<script src="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>`

Comment: @Mohsin Use cdn files for the libraries.

Comment: k k i am searching from a long time... but i couldn't get that cdn link of comiseo.daterangepicker can you please paste here that link.....

Comment: The best way is to download the files and keep it locally from here https://github.com/tamble/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/tags

Comment: kamlesh bhai my fiddle is not working jsfiddle.net/mohsinshaikh/o7b42294 your fiddle is perfect ! Why ? please click on my fiddle

Comment: @Mohsin You didn't include jQuery,jQueryUI libraries in the fiddle. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/o7b42294/1/